# writing to pbm file using java ImageIo

Tags: java, pdf, image-processing, pdfbox, javax.imageio

I am trying to convert pages of a pdf to .pbm images. I am using following code for conversion:

```
for (int i=0; i<pages.size(); i++) {
        PDPage singlePage = (PDPage) pages.get(i);
        int pageno=i+1;
        BufferedImage buffImage = null;
        String imagefilename=prefix+"-"+pageno+".pbm";
        try {
            buffImage =  singlePage.convertToImage();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("Font not found");
            return;
        }
        try {
            File output=new File(imagefilename);
            if (buffImage!=null){
                ImageIO.write( buffImage, "pbm", output);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File can not be written, check permission?");
        }
    }
```

When I am trying to write to png files, this seem to work perfectly, but I can not write to pbm files. `ImageIO.write( buffImage, "pbm", output);` returns `false`. What can be a possible remedy?

Comment: `ImageIO` doesn't support "pbm" format out of the box, you need to find a library that can read/write the "pbm" format and supports the requirements of the `ImageIO` API

Comment: @MadProgrammer isn't that an answer? :-) I suggest trying JAI ImageIO (the PNM plugin).

Comment: I searched with the query "JAI ImageIO the PNM plugin" but can't figure out from the results how to use this in producing pbm images. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @rivu Download the JAI ImageIO package from http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/ (if you don't find a package for your platform, just download any of them, but you won't get native optimized plugins). You should then get the PNM plugin (Portable aNy Map) that reads/writes PBM (b/w), PGM (grey) and PPM (color).